# How to dynamically add mesh from Object3D to new Object in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I am a complete newbie to 3d programming and have been working with three.js just over a week now. I have managed to load multiple collada and obj files, and managed to get perspectives, trackballs, everything working from examples. However, now I am stuck and need some help. For reference you can see the file i'm posting about at the following url:

http://shaman-labz.appspot.com/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

This page is basically straight from the examples, except that i am loading up an obj file, which has all these objects as meshes. what i am working on now is after loading the obj, i am going to iterate through all the geometries in the object and extract them so that i can drop them in the scene one a time when i need them, or have them float around like bubbles or something. I was thinking to maybe try to use the fresnel example, but this is where i'm hitting up against the boundaries of my understanding, and some terminology escapes me.

My question is, when this runs, the object that returns and is added to the scene after load has all these gems in it together.

So instead of the following lines:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var object = event.content;
    object.position.y = - 100;
    scene.add( object );
});
loader.load( 'obj/gems/24.obj', 'obj/gems/24.mtl' );
```

So what i'm doing is when the object returns, i look at the internals in debug/break mode, and i see that it's an object3D and object.children is an array of 25 meshes...and each of those meshes would be one of my 'gems' that i want to work with individually.

So here's where i get lost...when i grab the 'mesh' do i need to strip out the underlying geometry and create a new mesh?

on this page, you can see what i tried to accomplish:

http://shaman-labz.appspot.com/webgl_loader_obj_mtl2.html

the only major difference is in this section of code:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
        var object = event.content;
        var pos=0;
        for(var i=0; i< object.children.length; i++){
            var m = object.children[i];
            var gem = new THREE.Object3D();
            gem.name=m.name;
            gem.add(m);                     
            gem.position.x = -10;
            gem.position.y = -10;
            gem.position.z = pos;
            scene.add( gem );
            pos = pos - 10;
    }
});
loader.load( 'obj/gems/24.obj', 'obj/gems/24.mtl' );
```

notice that only 13 of the 25 gems show up from the collection, and also note how they are scattered, indicating that they are somehow still linked to some higher-order relationships that i am unable to set with position properly (it's like each mesh is somehow offset relative to it's original positioning in the original object loaded...thinking this has to do with world matrix?

Comment: Maybe this might shed some light: http://people.mozilla.com/~sicking/webgl/ray.html

Comment: You have at least 4 questions in the body of your post -- plus a question in the title. Create a post that is useful to others by asking one, specific question.

Comment: well, there's really only two questions, but who's counting? i'll update the question and break it out...thanks.